# Download Data For Only Visible Cells - Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to load data from Firebase without loading all the data at the same time. I want to load the first 20 child nodes and then as I scroll down in the tableView I want 20 more to be loaded and so on.

```
BASE_URL.child("names").queryOrderedByChild("time").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        self.names = []
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {

                if let namesDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let name = Name(key: key, dictionary: nameDictionary)                        
                    self.names.insert(name, atIndex: 0)
                }
            }

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
       })
    })
```

After This I have my TableView - Delegate and Datasource

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) to limit the number of items being returned, and when you scroll down, you can just call the data query again with `queryStartingAtValue` set (provided you already specified an order)

Comment: I think the code snippet from the documentation would suffice. Unfortunately I'm still learning swift on my days off, so I really can't help you with providing an example